# I got an error while importing dividend from R

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to import dividend from R. Some of stocks have errors, and I have no idea what they mean about.

Here are codes I use:

```
library(quantmod)


mdate <- "2016-01-04"
edate <- "2016-09-03"

Tick <- c("FAM","FCT","FEI","MAIN","WSR","ERF","ETB","ETG","ETJ","ETV","ETW",
          "ETX","ETY","EVG","EVN","EVT","EXG","KIO","MNE","MNP","MPA","MQT",
          "MQY","MTR","MTT","MUA","MUB","MUC","MUE","MUH","MUI","MUJ","MUNI",
          "MUS","MVF","MVT","MYC","MYD","MYF","MYI","MYJ")
  

Dividend_160104 <-
  lapply(Tick,
         function(x) {
           try(getDividends(x, from= mdate, to= edate, src="yahoo"),
               silent = TRUE)
         })
names(Dividend_160104) <- Tick
```

[image]

With the symbols, from 19th which is "MNE", errors show up; "Error in open.connection(file, "rt")
If I run with just a few symbols, there is no error, but I have more than three thousands symbols.
A few days ago I formatted my hard drive and reinstalled R in my portable hard drive. Is it because of this? Anybody know why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partly has to do with tickers that are not valid for yahoo. MNE is not a valid ticker and will give an error. As this issue impacts on how dividends are retrieved, an error here will fail the following tickers as well.

For more info see [github issue 314](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/314). At the time of writing, this issue is being handled by the developer.